# How to pass a 2D array to a function, when there is an undefined variable? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, vector

I want to pass a 2D array to a function. I have an array [m][n] and when I pass it to a function I want it to have those exact m & n variables that are defined in the int main(). Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void printBack(int b[][]);
int main()
{
    int m, n;
    int a[m][n];
    cout << "Enter the amount of rows:";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter the amount of columns:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter element a[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]:";
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << printBack(a);

    return 0;
}
void printBack(int b[][])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "Element a[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]:" <<b[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I do the function with 3 arguments?

Also, if I could get a vector version of this, I'd be really happy. I don't know how vectors work with 2D arrays.

Comment: `m` and `n` are not even defined to have a definite value when you declare `a`, not mentioning they must be compile-time constants. Use `std::vector`. They work with `std::vector`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all though some compilers have their own language extensions nevertheless Variable Length Arrays is not supported by the C++ Standard.

Moreover in your program variables `m` and `n` were not initialized before declaring array `a`. So your program is ill-formed and has undefined behavior.

You could use standard class `std::vector` instead of the array or you could dynamically allocate arrays of appropriate sizes.

This statement

```
cout << printBack(a);
```

also does not make sense because function `printBack` is declared as having return type void.

If to dynamically allocate arrays yourself then the program can look the following way

```
// declaring array

#include <iostream>

void printBack( int **a, int m, int n );

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rows: ";
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of columns: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    int **a = new int *[m];
    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ) a[i] = new int[n];


    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter element a[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]: ";
            std::cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }

    printBack( a, m, n );

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ) delete [] a[i];
    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}

void printBack( int **a, int m, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Element a[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]:" << a[i][j]<< std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If to use the standard class std::vector then the program can look like

```
// declaring vector

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printBack( const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &v );


int main()
{
    int m, n;

    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rows: ";
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of columns: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v( m, std::vector<int>( n ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter element v[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]: ";
            std::cin >> v[i][j];
        }
    }

    printBack( v );

    return 0;
}


void printBack( const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &v )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Element v[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "]:" << v[i][j]<< std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```